# Howto recover from neo4j cypher error: Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, corruption

Heads up that I also posted this on Neo4j GITHUB issues, which may not have been the correct place and am now cross-posting here for help.

I have had several neo4j server crashes due to low memory that I believe have left my database in a corrupt state. Basically the Cypher web entry thought the database was unplugged, and I had to forceably quite the Neo4j Community app, which had become non-responsive. Eventually I got into a state where most large queries involving certain nodes (:SNP) give errors. For example

```
match (s:SNP)-[r]-() where s.name > 'rs55' delete r, s
Node with id 15244864
Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound
```

OR

```
match (s:SNP)-[r]-() where s.name< 'rs55' delete r, s
Node with id 15244864
Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound
```

OR even

```
match (s:SNP) return count(s)
Node with id 15244864
Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound
```

I searched for "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound" and have tried suggestions from accepted answers found there.

Removing the schema/label and restarting the server did not help.

I have also tried reindexing :SNP(name), however, the index does not populate completely and a schema commands says the index Failed

```
 ON :SNP(name)               FAILED
```

Other than java heap errors I don't see any mention in neo4j.0.0.log or console.log or messages.log.

If anyone has suggestions on how to delete all SNPs (and I can reload) or otherwise recover without reloading a lot of other existing data please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try by deleting the schema label store, this will be recreated at db restart

- Shutdown the database
- go to your neo4j directory
- `cd data/graph.db`
- `rm -rf schema/label`
- restart Neo4j

Second solution: use a shell-tools to copy and fix your db to another store directory.

See https://github.com/jexp/store-utils

Comment: Thanks Christophe. neither approach solved the problem. The first had no effect and the second failed trying to make a copy of the database. It threw a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.InvalidRecordException: PropertyRecord[54372961] not in use